# Handling a ValidationError from inputs not conforming to a provided args_schema with a structured tool in langchain

Tags: python, error-handling, pydantic, langchain, py-langchain

I am trying to come up with the correct way to capture and handle a pydantic `ValidationError` caused by structured tool arguments not conforming to a provided `args_schema`.

I am creating structured tools with the `StructuredTool.from_function(...)` and providing an `args_schema`.  On occasion, I'll have errors due to the arguments not conforming to the schema (missing certain arguments, for example).

I'd like to find a way to pass in an error handling callback to handle the resulting `ValidationError` and recover from it (with some custom logging as well) without having the agent stop executing.

The functionality of the [handle_tool_error](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/tools/custom_tools#handling-tool-errors) argument is very similar to what I need. However it does not fit here because I need to be able to enter my tool code to raise a `ToolException` that the passed in handler callable can respond to.  The `ValidationError` is raised outside of my tool code, so I can't raise a `ToolException` in response.

My current approach is making all of the members of my `args_schema` be optional, and then check for `None` in my tool code, however I don't like this approach as the arguments are not optional, and I'd like my schema to be correct. Additionally, this workaround essentially means I have to predict the failures I'll get (missing fields, for example), and if I fail to predict correctly, my agent will stop executing.

I looked through langchain docs, but was not able to find a recommended approach.